# Drawing a Multi-Column Table with Latex

Tags: tables, formatting, vertical-alignment, diagrams, text

I am trying to draw exactly the same table below (Please pay attention to the vertical text at the very left):
[image]

How can implement such a thing in LaTeX?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables / https://ctan.org/topic/table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (complete with your text):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
        \begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
            \toprule
            &   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Aspect} \\ \cmidrule(l){3-6}
            &   & 1     & 2    & 3    & 4    \\
            \midrule

            \multirow{3}{5pt}{\rot{Tense}} & a & a1    & a2   & a3   & a4   \\
            & b & b1    & b2   & b3   & b4   \\
            & c & c1    & c2   & c3   & c4   \\ \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Many many thanks for the very helpful answer. It perfectly works as I wanted it to.

Comment: My job is done! And yours?

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean sorry I didn't get it.